# How to pass `this` to typeahead.js event

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typeahead.js, react-router

I'm using the typeahead.js library for search within my app. I've put together the following search but unfortunately at the end, I can't access `this`. Here's the current code:

```
$('#search-field').typeahead({hint:false, minLength: 2}, {
  configSetings: settings,
}).bind('typeahead:select', function(obj, datum) {
  this.history.pushState(null, `/term/${datum.permalink}`);
});
```

I've attempted to call `.bind(this)` to the `typeahead:select` event but when I do I end up with an error which states:

> Uncaught TypeError: m.push is not a function

I have no idea how to resolve this. Any ideas? I'm using ReactJS, Webpack, and Typeahead.js.

Comment: elements don't have `history` , it's a `window` property

Comment: @charlietfl this is reactjs using react-router and I've imported the History module. That essentially adds a history attribute to the component.

Comment: Use an arrow function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('#search-field').typeahead({hint:false, minLength: 2}, {
  configSetings: settings,
}).bind('typeahead:select', (function(obj, datum) {
  this.history.pushState(null, '', `/term/${datum.permalink}`);
}).bind(this));
```

Comment: So neither of these work at this point :(

Comment: I didn't realize that you're using the react-router + history module.   Can you post more code and/or create a runnable example eg. jsfiddle, etc?

Comment: here's a Gist: https://gist.github.com/biznickman/2a730fb615e3010b364a

Comment: I figured out the issue .. it was the location of calling .bind(this). If you attach it to the 'typeahead:selected' function, it resolves things.

Comment: Here's the solution: https://gist.github.com/biznickman/c7b0927a5f56591cd002

Comment: if you update your solution to attach the bind to the the typeahead:select callback function I'll mark it correct